# How do I make a fixed header that will cover iframes containing flash ads as my page scrolls?

Tags: flash, iframe, drop-down-menu, ads, wmode

I cannot use wmode=transparent/opaque in the flash object to force it to obey my page's zindex because of the ad provider-controlled cross-domain iframe.

I've tried to use Google closure's iframemask, but it doesn't work on other iframes (or flash objects within iframes); it does appropriately cover flash objects and similar elements, but I can't layer parts of my div on top of that, either (say, if I wanted a drop down menu that dropped over a flash ad inside an iframe.)

I've tried using an iframe shim/iframe cut-out - like hack by positioning an empty iframe above my ad iframe and below the div that contains content: I can get the div that contains content to show over the flash ad, but the ad disappears completely, not partially, and it only works in Firefox and Chrome, not in IE. It also doesn't work when I have a fixed header div and try to scroll the ad under it. I've tried setting the z-index of the content iframe quite high relative to the flash ad iframe and my empty iframe, but that doesn't work.

I've thought about setting the ad iframe to have display: none. This hides the iframe but doing this smoothly (with the fixed div as a header and the user scrolling the flash ad past this header div) seems difficult.

Any ideas on how to position divs over *parts of* an embedded flash ad? Or even over an embedded flash ad cross-browser with a fixed div header and the ads scrolling past? You guys are my last hope.